# Covering maps $p:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have to solve the following exercise:

> Show there aren't covering maps $p:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^2$.

**My attempt**

Considere the case $n\neq 2$. Assume exists a covering map $p:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$  a point. Without loss of generality, we can consider $B_{\varepsilon}(x)=:V_x$ as an open neighbourhood of $x$. By definition of covering map, we must have:

$1)\,\,\,p^{-1}(V_x)=\dot{\cup}_{j\in J} U^x_j$ is disjoint union of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$;

$2)\,\,\,p_{|U_j^x}: U_j^x\to V_x$ is homeomorphism.

Since an open set set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented as union of balls, by $2)$ we have an homemorphism between a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For clarity, let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ two balls. If $U\approx V$ ($\approx$ is used to denote two homeomorphic spaces), then in particular exist a continuous map $f:V\to U$ s.t. $f^{-1}$ is continuous. If we remove a point, we must have $V\setminus\{p\}\approx U\setminus \{f(p)\}$. But $\pi_1({U\setminus \{f(p)\}}\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1({V\setminus \{p\}})$ is trivial. So we have a contradiction.

**Questions**

$1)$ Is this proof correct? I'd be glad if someone has an alternative one.

$2)$ Is the statement actually true for $n=2$?

Comment: Looks good to me! Also every homeomorphism is a covering map so this does not work for $n=2$

Comment: I agree with @A name. Depending on how precise you want or need to be, you could spend a couple of words on why you can take $U$ to be a ball and why you can remove a point and obtain a homeomorphism again (both things are very easy, of course, verging on the obvious: I am nitpicking but if you don't feel the need to be this finicky that's ok). Last nitpick: usually one would say "we have a contradiction".

Comment: @Aname thank you for the feedback

Comment: @milore Indeed, I could explain what you pointed out. But it is only a skecth of the proof, so I did not include all details. Ty

Comment: Note this argument does not actually require a covering map. It shows more generally that there is no local homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. In fact, it generalizes immediately to there being no local homeomorphism between an $n$-dimensional and a $2$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: @Thorgott So could I have used the fact that there isn't a local homeomophism between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ to prove the thesis?

Comment: Sure, if you already knew that fact (because covering maps are local homeomorphisms). But what I'm saying is that you have actually proved this fact already by your argument.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you, unfortunately we studied only the definition of manifold :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n > 2$ your argument has a gap. You claim

> By $2)$ we have an homemorphism between a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Clearly the homeomorphic image of an open ball $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open simply connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$, but why is it homeomorphic to an open ball $U \subset \mathbb R^2$ which you use to show $\pi_1({U\setminus \{f(p)\}})\cong\mathbb{Z}$?

Actually this is a non-trivial result; it is covered for example by the                       [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) of complex analysis.

An alternative approach is to use the fact that $\mathbb R^n$ is simply connected, thus $p : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^2$ would be a universal covering. But universal covering spaces are unique up to homeomorphism so that $\mathbb R^n \approx \mathbb R^2$. Now your fundamental group argument applies.

For $n = 2$ you can the identity on $\mathbb R^2$ as a covering map.

For $n = 1$ you need a separate but elementary argument. The existence of a covering implies that some open disk $U$ in $\mathbb R^2$ would be homeomorphic to a connected open subset of $\mathbb R$, i.e. to an open interval $J$. This is impossible because removal of a point disconnects $J$, but not $U$.

**Update.**

Here is a proof that an open ball in $\mathbb R^n$ cannot be homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ which avoids the discussion what this open subset looks like. This clearly suffices to prove the non-existence of a covering map.

Assume that $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open ball and $U \subset \mathbb R^2$ is an open subset homeomorphic to $V$. Let $x$ be the center of $V$. Then $V \setminus \{x\}$ would be  homeomorphic to $U \setminus \{y\}$ for some $y \in U$. There exists an open ball $B \subset \mathbb R^2$ with center $y$ such that $B \subset U$. We have $B \setminus \{y\} \simeq S^1$, thus $\pi_1(B \setminus \{y\}) \cong \mathbb Z$. We conclude that $\pi_1(U \setminus \{y\}) \ne 0$: Consider the inclusion-induced homomorphisms $a : \pi_1(B \setminus \{y\})  \to \pi_1(U \setminus \{y\})$, $b : \pi_1(U \setminus \{y\})  \to \pi_1(\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{y\})$. Then $ba: \pi_1(B \setminus \{y\})  \to  \pi_1(\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{y\})$ is also inclusion-induced and clearly an isomorphism between non-trvial groups. Thus it cannot factor throgh the trival group.

Since $\pi_1(V \setminus \{x\}) = 0$, we get a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I said $V \approx U$ because if $p$ is a covering, it is a local homeomorphism, and wlog I assumed $U$ an open ball because open balls are a base for the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it wrong? Assuming that, I get a contradiction so there can be no covering

Comment: @SineoftheTime Of course you can assume that $U$ is an open ball in $\mathbb R^2$. But it is not obvious that if $V \approx U$, then $V \approx$ **open ball in $\mathbb R^n$**. It is a contractible open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, but why is it a ball? This is the gap.

Comment: I see, thank you for your time